# Connecting to LocalDB from Visual Studio Online Build Server

Tags: tfs, f#, azure-devops, localdb, type-providers

I have a library project that has a local MDF file (LocalDB) and uses the following connectionstring:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True
```

The code needs to access the DB in compilation time (F# Type Provider). It works fine locally but it fails when it is compiled on the Visual Studio Online Build Server (TFS) with the following error:

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=26085; handshake=248;

I checked and it looks like LocalDB is installed on the build servers: http://listofsoftwareontfshostedbuildserver.azurewebsites.net/

Any ideas? Do I need special permissions to access LocalDB?

Thanks!

Comment: not used online, but can you connect to the DB? are you using SQL2012 or sql 2014. are you publishing your db as part of the build?

Comment: I can connect to the DB in my machine. I am using /v11.0 that is SQl2012 and both the mdf and ldf files are marked as "content" and "copy always"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by initializing LocalDb in a post-build event.  You might need to put it in a pre-build event if your build itself is accessing the database.

I wanted to have a dynamic LocalDb database created every build in order to access it from my unit test suite.  I decided to use the RimDev.AutomationSql package to allow my unit tests to programmatically create the LocalDb instance rather than checking in a .mdf file. (See http://www.nuget.org/packages/RimDev.Automation.Sql/)

According to the RimDev.Automation.Sql github readme, https://github.com/ritterim/automation-sql, even though LocalDb is installed, it may not be initialized.

> You may have LocalDB installed, but never initialized the instance on
>   your machine. Run this command via command prompt.
>
> LocalDB SQL Express 2014
>
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe"
>   create "v12.0" 12.0 -s
>
> LocalDB SQL Express 2012
>
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe"
>   create "v11.0" 11.0 -s